# Slack node js program running session shut down

Tags: node.js, slack-api

Sorry to disturb. I am programming a Slack robot to reply user message by using the API

In the morning, it works totally okay. Then after I returned back from my office it just shut down and show me this error

```
Jiatongs-MacBook-Pro:news-bot jiatongli$ node index.js 
Assertion failed: token must be defined
/Users/jiatongli/Desktop/news-bot/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:105
            throw e;
            ^

Error: not_authed
    at _api.then.fail (/Users/jiatongli/Desktop/news-bot/node_modules/slackbots/index.js:46:33)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/jiatongli/Desktop/news-bot/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:773:56)
    at callFns (/Users/jiatongli/Desktop/news-bot/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:24:35)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at _api.then.fail (/Users/jiatongli/Desktop/news-bot/node_modules/slackbots/index.js:46:19)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/jiatongli/Desktop/news-bot/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:773:56)
    at callFns (/Users/jiatongli/Desktop/news-bot/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:24:35)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Jiatongs-MacBook-Pro:news-bot jiatongli$
```

I personally have no idea what is going on because it seems like the program itself do not have bug. What i miss?

Here is the code in my index.js file:

```js
var SlackBot = require("slackbots");
var request = require("request");
var NewsAPI = require("newsapi");
var unirest = require("unirest");

var API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
var Slack_API = process.env.Slack_API;
// create a bot
var bot = new SlackBot({
    token: Slack_API,
    name: "aloha-ai"
});

bot.on("message", msg => {
    switch (msg.type) {
        case "message":
            // we only want to listen to direct messages that come from the user
            if (msg.channel[0] === "D" && msg.bot_id === undefined) {
                getRandomTechNews(postMessage, msg.user)
            }
            break
    }
})

const postMessage = (message, user) => {
    bot.postMessage(user, message, {
        as_user: true
    });
}

const getRandomTechNews = (callback, user) => {


    unirest.get("https://nuzzel-news-v1.p.rapidapi.com/news?count=10&q=product")
        .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "nuzzel-news-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
        .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", API_KEY)
        .end(function (response) {

            var newsJSON = response.body;

            var news = "*Viral News* in product : \n\n\n\n";
            for (i = 0; i < newsJSON.results.stories.length; i++) {
                news += "_Excerpt:_   \n" + ">" + newsJSON.results.stories[i].excerpt + "\n"
                news += "_Let's see the article!_ \n" + newsJSON.results.stories[i].url + "\n\n\n"
            };
            callback(news, user);
        });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message seems to indicate that your program is not authenticated with the Slack API: `Error: not_authed`

Since you are retrieving your API key and token from environment variables:

```
var API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
var Slack_API = process.env.Slack_API;
```

my guess is that you have started a new terminal session where you have not yet set that environment variable, or you are on a different computer where it is not set.

Before running your program, try exporting those variables from the command line:

```
export API_KEY=<my-api-key>
export Slack_API=<my-token>
```

If you have security concerns about your API keys showing up in your bash history you can do one of two things (these are examples of things that I do, but there are probably better, safer practices out there):

1. You can put an empty space before your command `[space]export API_KEY=<my-api-key>` instead of `export API_KEY=<my-api-key>`. [This will make it so the command does not show up in your history](https://www.maketecheasier.com/linux-command-line-history-incognito/).
2. You can put your `export` commands in a separate file called e.g., `~/.secrets` and then run the command `source ~/.secrets` which will run your `export` commands.

Probably these will give you a *sense* of security rather than actual security though, since you can just echo the value of the environment variables, but I personally like taking one of these steps as an extra precaution.

Comment: Thakn you for your response! @elethan. So I just type the export directly in terminal?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but I guess in theory you may have some security concerns about that because they will show up in your bash history. I will update my answer a little bit.

Comment: also you can start looking into `.env` files. something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @Rieder great! I am glad it worked! Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check mark!

Answer (score 0):

i use this answer and can solve it.

> Add a bot https://my.slack.com/services/new/bot and put the token

do you get token for your bot from above url:

did you set this ?